# How do I syntax a simple logarithm in a spreadsheet formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

[simple logarithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h14ls.jpg)

How do I syntax this question in a spreadsheet formula? Trying to find N. (see image on at top)
Don't know how to write the formula for this, or what function to use.

- s = 4
- e = 2000
- x = 1.2
- n = ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What have you tried? What are the difficulties you had when trying? This is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LOG` function:

```
=LOG(A2/B2,C2)
```

where:

- A2 = s
- B2 = e
- C2 = x

[image: Result]